# Trying to calculate memory occupied by objects

Tags: scala, memory, object, runtime

I am creating and passing objects from one actor to another. I need to calculate the memory that is used to create an object at run time ?? Is there a way of doing it?

I am trying to do something like this .

```
var x = Runtime.getRuntime().totalmemory()
object.create() // my function to create an instance of an object
var y = Runtime.getRuntime().freememory()
val memoryUsedForCreatingObject = x - y
```

Do you think this is the correct way of doing it?? Will it give me the correct result?? Please let me know

Comment: Can I recommend to camel case the `memoryusedforcreatingobject`? It's hard to read. How about `memoryUsedForCreatingObject`.

Comment: This is just for an example... i am using different variables for my real code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably JAMM: https://github.com/jbellis/jamm/

Comment: Can we use it in scala..can u let me know if what i am doing is wrong??

Comment: @CuriousGuy007 Yes we can, because Scala is interoperable with Java, and Jamm is a Java library. Btw, may I recommend to use only a single question mark?